# Mirror all GitHub activity in Azure DevOps (Azure Repos)

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-devops, mirroring, azure-repos

I have a case where I want to store everything in Azure DevOps (CI/CD, Scrum, Testing, Publishing), but I still want to host all the code on GitHub.

How do I mirror all branches/merges/commits/PRs/issues made in GitHub in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), in particular [Azure/github-actions](https://github.com/Azure/github-actions) (from the original repo [`actions/azure`](https://github.com/actions/azure)).

That allows, on GitHub events (like a push), to generate work on GitHUb side, that will interact with Azure.