# how can a git repository be automatically updated when imported to azure?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I have a git repository that has been imported to azure repos but when I make a new commit it doesn't reflect the new commit on azure, is there some config I need to enable to allow this?

Sorry if the question seems dumb but I have been navigating through the UI and I can't see how to achieve this

thank you for all your help

Comment: Where is the git repository hosted? For GitHub: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233148/mirror-all-github-activity-in-azure-devops-azure-repos? You can also just push your changes to two remotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your needs. You can refer to the sample I implemented using Azure pipelines(I assume your repository is imported from GitHub to azure repos):

1.Create a pipeline and choose your GitHub repo as source:

[image]

2.Here is my configuration of the yaml file:

```
trigger:
- '*'//This pipeline will run whenever you push an update to the GitHub repo

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: gitmirror@0//You can install this task in marketplace
  inputs:
    GitRepoUrl: 'https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/{Project Name}/_git/{Repo Name}.git'//This is the URL of Azure Repo, you need to add a personal access token in the URL
```

3.Now, when you update the files in GitHub, it will trigger the pipeline in Azure DevOps and then update your Azure repository.

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, is there any way to do this more easily? Like just turn on an option or something, the reason im asking is because I have around 250 repos to import, and to do this for every pipeline even so, create a pipeline for each repo seems like a lot :/

Comment: As far as I know, Azure DevOps does not have such a feature or extension like this.  You can also refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/1607#issuecomment-421246091).